E_LOW_MEMORY_CONDITION Query Execution lacks memory resource to complete (message: bad allocation)
I'm new to ADX and I need your support.
I used to use this query a week ago and it went well both in ADX and PBI
but somehow it shows an error today as attached in PBI (in ADX is still working).
E_LOW_MEMORY_CONDITION Query Execution lacks memory resource to complete (message: bad allocation)
This is what my query look like
let T1 = (crqs_result| where id_factory == "229" or id_factory == "232"//| where fe_created >=     datetime(2024-08-15)| distinct id_factory,id_pqs_history,id_defect,nm_result_green,nm_result_yellow,nm_result_red,fe_created|lookup kind=inner (vw_Quality_crqs| summarize arg_max(nm_version,) by id_defect|where id_factory == "232" or id_factory == "229")on id_defect//| where id_defect in (24392//,24391//,24387//,24380//,24363//,24342//,24314//,24286//,24275//,24262//,24255//,24248//,24246//,24243)| distinct id_factory,id_pqs_history,id_defect,nm_result_green,nm_result_yellow,nm_result_red,fe_created,id_crqs,de_crqs,de_defect,id_category,de_category,id_subcategory,de_subcategory);T1| join kind=inner hint.strategy=broadcast (Quality_crqs_historical| where id_factory == "229" or id_factory == "232"//| where id_pqs == 1723//| where id_line == 50250//| where dt_scheduled >= datetime(2024-08-15)| where isempty(dt_modified) == false // remove non-numerics| summarize arg_max(dt_modified,) by id_pqs_observation| distinct  id_factory,id_pqs_observation,id_pqs,id_line,dt_scheduled,fl_shift,fl_state,dt_modified)on $left.id_pqs_history == $right.id_pqs_observation| distinct  fe_created,id_factory,id_pqs_history,id_defect,id_crqs,de_crqs,de_defect,id_category,de_category,id_subcategory,de_subcategory,nm_result_yellow,nm_result_red,nm_result_green,id_line,fl_shift,fl_state,dt_scheduled,dt_modified| lookup kind=inner hint.strategy=shuffle (Line| summarize arg_max(fe_modification,*) by id_line| where id_factory  == "229" or id_factory =="232"| where fl_active == 1| where fl_deleted == 0| distinct id_line,de_line,id_factory,fe_modification)on id_line| distinct  fe_created,id_factory,id_pqs_history,id_defect,id_crqs,de_crqs,de_defect,id_category,de_category,id_subcategory,de_subcategory,nm_result_yellow,nm_result_red,nm_result_green,id_line,fl_shift,fl_state,dt_scheduled,dt_modified,de_line;


Try simplifying the query to identify the part causing the memory issue, and then reintroduce complexity incrementally.
